# Spring Boot container cannot connect to My SQL container

Tags: java, mysql, docker, kubernetes, devops

I have read all questions related the issue and controlled all points. It seems everything is ok with my codes but it doesn't connect anyway.
I got CONNECTION REFUSED error when I try to connect from container. (BTW. Everything is fine when I change URL and try to connect from localhost)

My java project

```
spring:
  datasource:
   url: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/bootdb
   username: root
   password: root
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    generate-ddl: true
```

My docker-compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bootdb
    networks:
      - testnetwork
  employee-jdbc:
    image: bago1/student:latest
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - testnetwork
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    links:
      - mysqldb
networks:
  testnetwork:
```

It successfully connects from my local host machine when I edit URL as

```
url: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/bootdb
```

1. DB works fine
2. They are on the same network
3. syntax is fine

Comment: Shouldn't  this

`url: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/bootdb` be

`url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bootdb` even for container deployment?

Comment: no. jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bootdb works when i call from local host

Comment: If you read through the Compose logs, is the application trying to connect before the database is ready?  The `links:` option is unnecessary and may activate an obsolete Docker networking mode; does deleting it make any difference?  (You should also be able to get rid of all of the `networks:` blocks but this wouldn't make a functional difference.)

Comment: I used without Networks and links as well. ghis is not a problem

Answer (score 0):

Add the `hostname` field in your docker compose like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    hostname: mysqldb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bootdb
  employee-jdbc:
    image: bago1/student:latest
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    links:
      - mysqldb
```

(Ps: don't need the add the `networks` field, the use of docker-compose creates automatically a network for your services)

(PS2: it's a good practice to use tag when using images (instead of using mysql:latest) )

Answer (score 0):

Remove ports configuration of MySQL container and insert:

```yaml
    expose:
      - 3306
```